# Some subtleties in direction of drag force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, projectile, drag

Consider a body released from a height $h$ and assume a drag force is linearly proportional to the velocity.  Then by Newton's Second Law, $$m\mathbf{\dot{v}} = \mathbf{F_g} + \mathbf{F_{drag}} = m\mathbf{g} -\mu \mathbf{v} $$  Take the positive $x$ axis upwards, then we can write $$m \mathbf{\dot{v}} = -mg \hat{x} - \mu v (-\hat{x})\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$ where $\mathbf{v} = v(-\hat{x})$  The decomposition is therefore $$m\frac{dv}{dt} = -mg + \mu v,$$ which when integrated yields an exponentially growing velocity, and hence there is a problem with the above.

I do not see where the problem is. The starting point is that $\mathbf{F_{drag}} = -\mu \mathbf{v}$ and since $\mathbf{v} = v (-\hat{x})$ in the coordinate system, we have the above. In $(1)$, it makes sense that the drag force and gravitational force are in opposite directions when the body falls down.

I looked in some books (in particular D. Morin P.63) and he has a sign reversal in the $\mu v$ term (i.e both terms on the right hand side of the equation are negative)  However, in this link, they have alternating signs (see Example 1,$\,$ $\approx$ half way down - just reversed coordinate system) http://www.math24.net/newtons-second-law-of-motion.html

Many thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies with inconsistent application of

$$\mathbf{v} = v (-\hat{x}) \,.$$

If you insist on this (and I wouldn't) then you must also have

$$ \mathbf{a} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{v}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} (- \hat{x}) \,, $$

which you have neglected the step from (1) to the next line.

---

In my opinion it would be preferable to have the direction of positive $\mathbf{v}$ agree with the direction of increasing $x$, exactly because otherwise you have to be very careful with signs like that.

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed fix the problem.  However, I do not see the reasoning behind Morin's equation (P.63 if you have access) $F = -mg - \mu v$ This implies both forces act downwards (since he assigned +ve $x$ upwards).

Comment: Yes. That's right. Positive $v$ is up, so the drag term goes by $-v$ and the gravitational term also points down. No problem there. Upward velocities will be rapidly reduced, and downward velocities will converge on a terminal velocity.

Comment: But the drag term should not be pointing down - the body is moving downwards and so drag should point upwards. (This has to be the case otherwise a terminal velocity could not exist since both forces would be acting in same direction). $\mathbf{F_d} = -\mu \mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is downwards, so $\mathbf{F_d}$ is upwards.

Comment: When the body is moving down $v < 0$ (I don't have access to that text but I assume it has $x$, $v$ and $a$ all positive in the same direction which is the sane way to assign the signs) so $-\mu v$ is positive.

Comment: I find it easier to use vectors; what would the corresponding vector equation be for the scalar equation $F = -mg -\mu v$? If $\hat{x}$ is upwards then there should be a term like $-mg\hat{x}$.  And since $\mathbf{F_{drag}} = -\mu \mathbf{v} = -\mu v (-\hat{x}) = + \mu v \hat{x}$

Comment: @CAF you did it again! The equation is already for $v$ in the upwards direction. You don't need to do that, you can just multiply the equation $F=-mg-\mu v$ by $\hat{x}$ and be done with it. The corresponding vector equation is $F \hat{x}=-mg\hat{x}-\mu v\hat{x}$ or $\mathbf{F}=-mg\hat{x}-\mu \mathbf{v}$.